# beautiful soup- Scraping a site with hidden tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to Scrape NBA.com play by play table so I want to get the text for each box that is in the example picture.
[image: example]
for example(https://www.nba.com/game/bkn-vs-cha-0022000032/play-by-play).

checking the html code I figured that each line is in an article tag that contains div tag that contains two p tags with the information I want, however I wrote the following code and I get back that there are 0 articles and only 9 P tags (should be much more) but even the tags I get their text is not the box but something else. I get 9 tags so I am doing something terrible wrong and I am not sure what it is.

this is the code to get the tags:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def contains_word(t):
    return t and 'keyword' in t
url = "https://www.nba.com/game/bkn-vs-cha-0022000032/play-by-play"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

div_tags = soup.find_all('div', text=contains_word("playByPlayContainer"))
articles=soup.find_all('article')
p_tag = soup.find_all('p', text=contains_word("md:bg"))
```

thank you!

Comment: Seems like these fields are loaded after the page using `js`. You will need to use something like `selenium` to extract this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Selenium since it's using Javascript and pass it to Beautifulsoup. Also `pip install selenium` and get the chromedriver.exe

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/game/bkn-vs-cha-0022000032/play-by-play")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
```